# D3JS making a bar chart where each row/data point contains multiple time segments

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to make a chart of sleeping sessions that looks something like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsnha.png

I currently have only been able to get it to draw one rectangle per data point. I'm wondering what the syntax would be to have it draw multiple rectangles associated with a single row/data point since each data point contains an array of sleeping sessions from that day.

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
var start;
var end;
var rectGrp = svg
    .append("g")
    .attr('transform', 'translate(' +padding.left+','+padding.top+')')
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(sleepArr)
    .enter()
    //I want to create one of these rectangles for all the sleeping sessions in that day
    .append("rect")
        .attr("x", (d) => {
            start = d.sessions[0].startTime;
            end = d.sessions[0].endTime;
            return xScale(start); 
        })
        .attr("width", (d) => {
            start = d.sessions[0].startTime;
            end = d.sessions[0].endTime;
            var width = end-start;
            return xScale(width);
        })
        .attr("y", (d) => yScale(d.date))
        .attr("height", yScale.bandwidth())
        .attr("fill", (d) => colors[getDayOfWeek(d.date)])
        .append("title")
        .text((d) => d.date);
```

I realize that I probably don't have a good understanding of how to use D3 yet and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With the enter/update/exit cycle one item in the data array should be bound to one element in the DOM. The enter selection is used to ensure we create one element for every item for which there is already not one corresponding element in the DOM. In your case the number of rectangles you want to draw is not the same as the number of people in your data array. The approach you have is great for a flat data structure, but we need to make nested selectAll statements in order to properly represent your data.

First, each item in `sleepArr` represents one person, so lets create one parent `g` for every person:

```
var sleepers = svg
  .append("g")
  .attr('transform', 'translate(' +padding.left+','+padding.top+')')
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(sleepArr)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", (d,i)=>...
```

*We probably want to do the vertical positioning here as all children of each parent `g` elements are the same.*

Second, we want to create child rectangles representing sleep sessions. We want one rectangle per session. The data array for these rectangles is the `sessions` property of the datum bound to each parent `g`, so we pass that to the data method:

```
sleepers.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) return d.sessions; }))
  .enter()
  .append("rect")
  .attr("x", ...
  ...
```

For each parent `g`, representing a single person, we select all child rectangles of each `g`, bind data, and enter the required rectangles in the appropriate `g`.

This way we keep a one to one relationship between data and elements representing them: one `g` per person, one `rect` per session. The items in `sleepArr` are bound to the parent `g` elements, and the items in the child data array are bound to the `rects`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Some of this is making sense. However, I'm confused on how you would suggest to use transform to do the vertical positioning of the parent g elements. Here's what I've got which isn't working:  ```    var rectGrp = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr('transform', 'translate(' +padding.left+','+padding.top+')')
        .selectAll("rect")
        .data(sleepArr)
        .enter()
        .append("g")
        .attr('transform', (d,i) => 'translate('+padding.left+','+yScale(d.date)+')')
        .append("title")
        .text((d) => d.date);```